# Layout incorrect on iPhone 5, correct on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

When I am running my application on the iPhone 4, it looks like everything is in the correct spots, but when I run it on an iPhone 5, the objects are floating around.  How do I make the iPhone 5 version look like the iPhone 4?  Please see screenshots at the following links.

How it looks on iPhone 4:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIEGN.png

How it looks on iPhone 5:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWSNY.png

Comment: How are you laying out your content?  Are you using auto layout, springs & struts or programmatic placement?  Are your devices both running the same version of iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your screen shot's I assume you need to apply **autolayout** on all component's so that all componenet could adjust well as per different screen size. If you are new to autolayout [check out this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) would help you in understanding and applying.